# How does one define a macro using variable to supply the form and have it function properly in SBCL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

After some feedback, I'm posting code that should reproduce the situation.

The purpose of my code is to generate and then execute a custom database query. The idea is to generate the query, define a macro with the query as the form, then execute the macro. Below is a very simplified idea of what's happening.

1. Define a function, which:
2. Defines our query string
3. And a macro whose form is the variable containing the query string
4. Then executes the macro

```
(defun test ()
  (defvar quer '(query (:select '* :from 'table)))
  (defmacro macquer () quer)
  (macquer))
```

This macro throws the below error when executed by the function, but not when executed alone. Thoughts?

```
STYLE-WARNING:
   MACQUER is being redefined as a macro when it was previously assumed to be a function.

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1000560083}>:
  COMMON-LISP-USER::MACQUER is a macro, not a function.
```

NB: The query is from the postmodern library which hooks up to PostgreSQL. I wanted to show you the real query, but this condition holds for any form that I've tried.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The things that will obviously go wrong if you try to reference a variable in a macro will be (1) the variable not being available at compile time at all (needing `eval-when`) and (2) the variable being computed and assigned at the wrong time. But the error message doesn't match these situations. What @adabsurdum said.

Comment: `define a macro, whose form is provided by a variable`, in which context would you use this macro?

Comment: Ordinarily you would call `defvar` or `defmacro` at the top level. Why are you writing a macro for this? A more detailed example of the actual problem to be solved may be helpful.

Comment: I think that as of V4 this question does now include an example which demonstrates the problem (or rather: the author's confusion).  I'm not whether it's really an appropriate question as it looks like some very basic confusion about what macros are which may be too large for SO.  But I'm voting to reopen it so it can be reconsidered anyway.

Comment: It would be nice to have more information about the motivation for writing this macro, but I think that the question is probably answerable now, too; I'll also vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer deals largely with the example given, and tries to explain why it can't work.  At the end is some guesswork about what you might be trying to do and how to achieve that.

### Times

First of all it's useful to informally define various 'times' in the processing of a form by a CL system.  These may be slightly different if the form is being compiled or merely evaluated, but they may not be.  These definitions are *informal* and *not completely correct*: they're enough to answer the question but I've skated over some details.

Here is a rough enumeration of the various times:

1. read time, when the text of the form is read from a stream of characters and turned into an expression of some kind;
2. macroexpansion time, when macros in the form are expanded until none remain;
3. compile time when the form is compiled;
4. possibly another time here when a representation of the compiled form is written to a file
5. evaluation time when the form is evaluated, which may also be load time if the previous step happened;
6. if the form is some kind of defining form (`defun`, `defvar` and so on), then there may be many later 'use times' when the function is called, or the variable is referred to.

The above times refer to a compiled implementation.  In practice some interpreted implementations, which do not have times (3) and (4), may tangle up times (2) and (5).  However you should always regard these times as happening *strictly in order*.  That's because they *do* happen strictly in order for a compiler, and because an implementation need not have an interpreter: the evaluator can work by compilation.  SBCL is an example of an implementation which (largely?) works this way.

This means that all macros in a form, apart from local macros, must be defined *properly before* evaluation or compilation starts, and anything they use in their expansion must therefore also be defined properly before evaluation or compilation starts.

### Some special cases in the file compiler

The above description concerns the times when processing a single form.  The file compiler has some additional behaviour which makes the language practical to use.  This additional behaviour concerns *top-level forms only* (there is a subtle definition about what 'top-level' means which I will skate over here).

When processing a top-level form which is a defining form then the file compiler is required to take special note of at least two cases

- if the form defines a dynamic variable then the compiler must take note that references to and bindings of this variable are special later in the file
- if the form defines a macro, then the compiler must make the macro available later in the file, so that uses of it can be expanded at compile time.

There may be other cases: these are the two that concern us here.

### Examples of how the file compiler deals with things

Consider the following source file

```
(defmacro with-foo ((foo) &body forms)
  `(call-with-foo (lambda (,foo)
                    ,@forms)))

(defun call-with-foo (f)
  ...
  (funcall f ...)
  ...)

(defun fash ()
  (with-foo (my-foo)
    (print my-foo)))
```

When compiling this the compiler is required to note that `with-foo` is a macro, and it will therfore be able to expand the use of it in `fash`.  It does *not* need to make the definition of `call-with-foo` available at compile time, and it will not in fact be available then.  This file is fine.

Here is a file which is *not* fine

```
(defvar *print-hi* '(print "hi"))

(defmacro printing-hi ()
  *print-hi*)

(defun cant-compile ()
  (printing-hi))
```

So, OK, what happens when compiling this file?

- firstly the compiler notes that `*print-hi*` is a special variable and creates code to define it at load time;
- then it notes the definition of `printing-hi` and also creates code to recreate it at load time;
- then it tries to compile `cant-compile`, expanding the macro `printing-hi` ... to a reference to `*print-hi*` *which does not yet exist*

The compilation thus fails.

Well, this is a common enough case that the designers of CL added a special hack to deal with it: you can tell the file compiler that certain toplevel forms should be evaluated immediately after compilation, and the results (side-effects, really) of this evaluation are thus available later in the compilation.  *There are many subtleties here* which I am skipping over, but here is how you would do this:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defvar *print-hi* '(print "hi")))

(defmacro printing-hi ()
  *print-hi*)

(defun can-now-compile ()
  (printing-hi))
```

The `eval-when` special operator, when used like this, tells the compiler that it should evaluate the `defvar` form, and thus define `*print-hi*` *at compile time*.  This means `printing-hi` can now be expanded at compile time and everything will be well.

Note one thing however: the value of `*print-hi*` that will be used is the value *at compile time* not any later value.  The effective definition of `can-now-compile` is

```
(defun can-now-compile ()
  (print "hi"))
```

And this *does not change* if you later change `*print-hi*`: the macro is already expanded.

### Your form and its evils

So now, consider your form:

```
(defun test ()
  (defvar quer '(query (:select '* :from 'table)))
  (defmacro macquer () quer)
  (macquer))
```

Let's approximate the expansion of the `defun`, `defvar` and `defmacro` macros which appear in this form and which the compiler will expand to give an expansion like this:

```
(progn
  ;; expansion of DEFUN
  ...
  ;; Something like this
  (setf (fdefinition 'test)
        (lambda ()
          (block test
            (progn
              ;; expansion of DEFVAR
              ...
              ;; this or some equivalent will probably be there
              ;; somewhere
              (eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
                (proclaim '(special 'quer)))
              ...
              ;; this or some equivalent will be there
              (unless (boundp 'quer)
                (setf (symbol-value 'quer)
                      '(query (:select '* :from 'table))))
              ...)
            (progn
              ;; expansion of DEFMACRO
              ...
              ;; Some equivalent of this must be there, the actual
              ;; macro function may be different
              (setf (macro-function 'macquer)
                    (lambda (...) quer))
              ...)
            (macquer))))
  ...
  'test)
```

There are still macros remaining in this: `setf` and `lambda`, but I'm not going to expand them as they're not interesting here.

OK, so this form now gets compiled.  The resulting code will, at evaluation time (so after compilation time!), install a definition for a function named `test`.  *There is no definition of `macquer`*, so the compiler will assume that this is a function call, as it should.

Note that, *even when this form is evaluated* neither the variable `quer` nor the macro `macquer` become defined: what happens is that a function, `test`, is defined and *calling `test`* will cause `quer` and `macquer` to be defined.

When `test` is later called, it will thus do three things:

- define a global special variable named `quer`;
- define a macro named `macquer`, perhaps even with the correct definition depending on how the compiler handles the unknown variable reference in its body;
- then attempt to call a *function* named `macquer` (and fail).

In addition the compilation process will almost certainly produce one, and perhaps two, warnings:

- a reference is made to a variable `quer` which is not known;
- a call to an an unknown function, `macquer` is made.

### Making this work part one

OK, so what's the underlying problem here?  It's that you are confusing the various times I've outlined above.  The function `test` is referring to something called `macquer`, but that is (or will later be) a macro which is defined only when and if the function is called.  This can't work.  The macro function itself, when compiled, attempts to refer to a variable, `quer` which is *also* not yet defined.

Additionally the function definition involves things like `defvar` and `defmacro` which *are almost never correct*: while this is technically legal, those forms are almost always a mistake when they occur other than at toplevel, where the compiler can notice them and treat them appropriately (see [compilation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_b.htm) and in particular [file compilation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bc.htm)).  And in this case they are a mistake.

The important thing here is that *macros are functions which transform source code to other source code*, and as such they need to be fully known at the point that source code is processed, either by the compiler or the interpreter, if there is one.  If the expansion of the macro refers to a variable then that variable must therefore also be known at that time.  If the expansion of the macro involves a call to a function then that function must be known at that time.

To make this 'work' you need to make sure that things are defined when you need them to be.  As an example, based on the above examples of the file compiler, this will work:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  ;; This variable must be defined at macroexpansion time
  (defvar *query* '(query (:select '* :from 'table))))

(defmacro querying ()
  *query*)

(defun test ()
  (querying))
```

This works and shows that the expansion of a macro can be just a variable whose value is the source-code you want, but that variable needs to be known about at macroexpansion time, and *the value that will be used will be its value at macroexpansion time*.

But the chances are that this is not what you want.  In particular this won't work:

```
(defun test ()
  (compute-query)
  (querying))

(defun compute-query ()
  (setf *query* ...))
```

`test` will use the value of `*query*` at compile time, not any later value.

### Making this work, part two

My guess is that you want to programmatically build up the query, and then evaluate it.  Well, the answer to that is not to use macros at all: Postmodern allows you to dynamically compile its s-sql language, and its `query` macro understands this.

So instead, do this, perhaps:

```
(defvar *default-query* 
  '(query (:select '* :from 'table)))

(defun test (&optional (query *default-query*))
  (query (sql-compile query)))
```

Note that `*default-query*` is now really an optional thing.  There are things you can't do this way, I think.  In particular `query` allows you to refer to lexical variables in the expansion which `sql-compile`, being a function, can't do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, ignis! This is incredibly useful for me as I lookmore into macros/compilation, etc. I have "On Lisp" by Graham and "Let over Lambda" by Hoyte -- any recommendations for other good resources to get a better picture re macros and compilation, etc? Your solution with sql-compile works perfectly.